# Cant build C project in Eclipse

Tags: c, embedded, eclipse-cdt, cortex-m, nuvoton

I want to dump a simple Hello World code in a Cortex M4 microcontroller.(Nuvoton [M487KM](https://www.nuvoton.com/export/resource-files/UM_NuMaker-M487KM_User_Manual_EN_Rev1.00.pdf))
All the tool, board support files and IDE are provided on the [website](https://www.nuvoton.com/board/numaker-pfm-m487km/?index=2) which are installed with the Eclipse IDE (NuEclipse GCC Windows).
After creating a basic Hello world project, I try to build the project but keep getting these errors that wont stop bothering me.

Here is the code: (main.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "NuMicro.h"

#define PLL_CLOCK           192000000

void SYS_Init(void)
{
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Init System Clock                                                                                       */
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Unlock protected registers */
    SYS_UnlockReg();

    /* Set XT1_OUT(PF.2) and XT1_IN(PF.3) to input mode */
    PF->MODE &= ~(GPIO_MODE_MODE2_Msk | GPIO_MODE_MODE3_Msk);

    /* Enable External XTAL (4~24 MHz) */
    CLK_EnableXtalRC(CLK_PWRCTL_HXTEN_Msk);

    /* Waiting for 12MHz clock ready */
    CLK_WaitClockReady(CLK_STATUS_HXTSTB_Msk);

    /* Set core clock as PLL_CLOCK from PLL */
    CLK_SetCoreClock(PLL_CLOCK);
    /* Set PCLK0/PCLK1 to HCLK/2 */
    CLK->PCLKDIV = (CLK_PCLKDIV_APB0DIV_DIV2 | CLK_PCLKDIV_APB1DIV_DIV2);

    /* Enable UART clock */
    CLK_EnableModuleClock(UART0_MODULE);

    /* Select UART clock source from HXT */
    CLK_SetModuleClock(UART0_MODULE, CLK_CLKSEL1_UART0SEL_HXT, CLK_CLKDIV0_UART0(1));

    /* Update System Core Clock */
    /* User can use SystemCoreClockUpdate() to calculate SystemCoreClock. */
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();



    /* Set GPB multi-function pins for UART0 RXD and TXD */
    SYS->GPB_MFPH &= ~(SYS_GPB_MFPH_PB12MFP_Msk | SYS_GPB_MFPH_PB13MFP_Msk);
    SYS->GPB_MFPH |= (SYS_GPB_MFPH_PB12MFP_UART0_RXD | SYS_GPB_MFPH_PB13MFP_UART0_TXD);
    /* Lock protected registers */
    SYS_LockReg();
}

/*
 * This is a template project for M480 series MCU. Users could based on this project to create their
 * own application without worry about the IAR/Keil project settings.
 *
 * This template application uses external crystal as HCLK source and configures UART0 to print out
 * "Hello World", users may need to do extra system configuration based on their system design.
 */

int main()
{

    SYS_Init();
    /* Init UART to 115200-8n1 for print message */
    UART_Open(UART0, 115200);
    /* Connect UART to PC, and open a terminal tool to receive following message */
    printf("Hello World\n");

    /* Got no where to go, just loop forever */
    while(1);

}
```

And these are the errors I get:

```
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':    hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':    hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':  hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':    hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':  hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':  hellowork           C/C++ Problem
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10 2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libc_nano.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':    hellowork           C/C++ Problem
make: *** [hellowork.elf] Error 1   hellowork           C/C++ Problem
recipe for target 'hellowork.elf' failed    makefile    /hellowork/Debug    line 56 C/C++ 

Problem
undefined reference to `_close' hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_fstat' hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_isatty'    hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_lseek' hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_read'  hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_write' hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: closer.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: fstatr.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: isattyr.c C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: lseekr.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: readr.c   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `errno'  hellowork       line 0, external location: c:\program files (x86)\gnu arm embedded toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: writer.c  C/C++ Problem
```

According to the NuEclipse [User Manual](https://www.nuvoton.com/resource-files/UM_NuEclipse_EN_Rev1.01.014.pdf), we need to set global Toolchain Settings which I did.
The path to Toolchain and Build tools is also mentioned.
Still the code keeps giving me these errors. I read online that it might be the "libc_nano.a" files issue but the those solutions have not helped me.
Can someone please help me!!

Comment: I suggest you try something simpler first and don't start with the very complex file handling. Start with toggling a io, then you may can send single characters. And then you can implement `putchar()` which is needed for `printf()` either by you or by a toolchain / library.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123  `putchar()` will already be implemented in the standard library (though you could override it of course).  What they both ultimately depend on ois `_write_r()` which is what the linker is complaining about.  The linker will continue to complain about that (and other syscalls) so long as they are not provided and the standard library is linked, no matter how simple he makes his code.

Comment: @Clifford I don't know the exact toolchain, all µC which i used `printf()` on (to be fair, i don't use `printf()` a lot on µC`) i had to supply `putchar()`. Anyway, point is that there needs to code that needs to do something with the `char`s he wants to print.

Comment: Why do you want to use `printf()` on a µC? Isn't that a bit overkill? There exist (almost) always a simpler solution than using `printf()`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 : No, but you do not need to know the toolchain to understand the linker errors.  You can in fact provide a `putchar()` to implement `printf` as an override of the library implementation - it will bypass all the stdio infrastructure supporting redirection, stderr, stdin, and file I/O streams.  But the linker errors will not go away - it will just mean that you might be able use non-working stubs.

Comment: Please open a command line prompt and try to build there, to check where the error comes from. I doubt that it is the IDE. It should be as simple as changing into the project's directory and calling make with the same arguments as the IDE.

Comment: To check whether or not `printf()` was the problem, I wrote a basic addition code. Sadly it failed to build as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Newlib C library for which you need to provide the *syscalls* stubs to couple the library to your hardware/runtime environment.

Many of the stubs only need dummy implementations.  To support `printf` you need to implement `_write_r()`.  To support a heap (`malloc()` *et al*), you need to implement `_sbrk_r`.

Details of the syscalls that need implementing can be found at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Reentrant-Syscalls, along with "minimal" implementation examples at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Stubs.  Noting that the re-entrant versions can simply map to (or be implemented in the samr way as) the non-reentrant versions if you are not multi-threading or for very simple implementations.  The `_r` variants allow for a thread specific `errno` for example.

You simply need to create a source file with these functions implemented and link them to your project to resolve the links.  It looks like your tool chain already provides for this in these files:

```
closer.c
fstatr.c
isattyr.c
lseekr.c
readr.c 
writer.c
```

Those are the ones that need modifying, reimplementing or possibly they are ok, but you need to provide the `errno` support (a global) indicated by the linker error.  In a multi-threaded environment `errno` needs "switching" per thread (ideally - or just never rely on `errno`), but otherwise a single global is all that is needed most likely (also as described at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Stubs).

Comment: I got my hands on a pre-tested project file, I imported it in the Eclipse IDE, and it worked!! I just copy pasted this code in that projects main file, and that worked too. I still strongly believe that it was some Toolchain settings problem because it only works if I keep editing that exact file over and over again.

Comment: @HarshalChavan Re. _"strongly believe that it was some Toolchain settings problem"_ - then you have understood noting I have said.  The syscalls stubs are necessarily _target specific_ - you have to provide them for your target.  Your "working" project clearly already includes those stubs.  The linker errors are very clear. The project was missing those stubs.  You only posted the error messages, had you posted the complete compile/link log with the command line invitations the precise problem would be evident (and would show all toolchain  "settings" that you think are the problem.